# Core Data: setPrimitiveValue and saving changes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, save, primitive

In Core Data, is there some trick to saving changes to managed objects' attributes when the changes were made with setPrimitiveValue versus the object's regular accessor methods?

I've switched to using setPrimitiveValue and setPrimitiveAttributeName in a few scenarios in order to avoid triggering my FRC's notification methods (controllerWillChangeContent, controllerDidChangeObject, etc.).  In both cases, after making changes to the core data objects and saving the managed object context, the changes look like they were made (i.e I can see the changes with NSLog) but they are actually lost (i.e. if I exit the application in the simulator and rerun it, the FRC reloads, and the attributes I thought I changed are gone).

The save code is copied from Apple examples, and the managed object classes for my Core Data entities  are as-generated by Xcode.  Everything I've read from Apple and on this site suggests this is a valid use of the setPrimitive methods, though I admit I must be lacking a some understanding of how these setPrimitive functions really work...

Code:

```
// header file for Managed Object sub class generated by xcode from my core data entity:
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface PlannedItem :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * ptType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * whenOrder;
@end

// .m file for Managed Object subclass
#import "PlannedItem.h"
@implementation PlannedItem 

@dynamic ptType;
@dynamic whenOrder;

@end

// trying to use setPrimitiveValue or even setPrimitiveWhenOrder to modify
// this is in my view controller
// p is a pointer to PlannedItem
int oldOrder = [p.whenOrder intValue];
[p setPrimitiveValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(oldOrder +1)] forKey:@"whenOrder"];


// later on in same method, save is executed.  
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
NSLog(@"Saved");
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: hmmmmm.... looks like willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey are what I'm looking for.  I can't post an answer yet but I will later on if I don't happen to come across a better suggestion...

Comment: I take it back - willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey  are helping, but they cause the FRC to once again invoke the content change notifications to the delegate.  I guess I want my FRC and everything to be up to date on the changes I have made using setPrimtiveValue, but I also don't wan't those content change notification methods to run in this case.  I guess I can't have it both ways, can I?

Comment: the KVO calls to willChange etc. are a must Core Data starts acting up after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the code in the notification handlers to execute (BTW, why would you want that?), it might be easier to disable *that*, instead of completely avoiding the notifications. Also, remember that Core Data uses those notifications to update your relationships and maintain coherence in your model when you make changes.

In your view controller, setup a boolean and set it according to your need to execute the notification handler code or not. Then, in your handlers check that flag, e.g.:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if (notificationIgnored) {
        return;
    }
    // rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: The reason i didn't want the code notification handlers to execute is that the attribute being updated is simply a display order for a UITableView backed by a fetchedResultsController.

Comment: So when I add an object, right now I update the display order on all subsequent rows.  Using a flag as you describe should work, however for me it has not turned out to be a very clean solution, and it gives me weird bugs.  I was hoping I could use setPrimitiveValue to avoid those extra updates from triggering the handlers in the first place.  Alas the solution octy describes looks like the best option.